# What is the opposite of ^?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have been given this:

$\text{XP} = (\text{level}^3)\cdot10$

So for example 270 XP = Level 3

My problem is I already have the value of XP, so how can I figure out what level would be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to solve $a=b^n$, you use $\sqrt[n]{}$ to get $\sqrt[n]{a}=b$.

Comment: 270 / 10 = 27.    √27 = 5.196152422706632.   I need to be able to get 3 as a return value

Comment: Ryuk: The symbol $\sqrt[n]{}$ refers to the $n$th root, not the square root. Here, $\sqrt[3]{27} = 3$, because $3^3=27$. Similarly, $\sqrt[5]{32}=2$, because $2^5=32$.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your level is $$\sqrt[3]{\frac{XP}{10}}.$$
If you have trouble computing cube roots, try $$\exp\left(\frac13\cdot\ln\frac {XP}{10}\right).$$

Comment: @Ryuk I'm guessing you'll also have to $\operatorname{floor}$ the result, since I assume levels are integer values.

Comment: 270 / 10 = 27.    √27 = 5.196152422706632.   I need to be able to get 3 as a return value

Comment: @Ryuk While $\sqrt{27}\approx5.196\ldots$, we have $\sqrt[3]{27}=3$.

Comment: Ah right, now I just have to figure out how do this in JAVA

Comment: In Java,  you can use `pow(xp/10, 1/3)` to calculate the cube root of $\frac{xp}{10}$.

Comment: Right: in general $\sqrt[n]{a} = a^{\frac{1}{n}}$.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't compute cube roots, you can always iterate.
Let $N$ be the value you're trying to find the cube root.
$$
x_n = (2x_{n-1}+\frac{N}{x_{n-1}^2})/3
$$

Start with a reasonable guess for $x_0$ and iterate when the result stabilizes w.r.t. your desired accuracy.

For example, $N=28,\quad x_0=3.$  The iteration will result in values of $x_n$
$$
3 \\
3.037037037 \\
3.036589038 \\
3.036588972 \\
3.036588972
$$